# google chrome prints in black & white only

Tags: macos, snow-leopard, google-chrome, printing

Using Chrome v20 on OSX 10.6.8 on two boxes. Chrome Print dialog opens without the color/b&w option, always prints in b&w regardless of which printer I choose (I have several available). If I select to use system dialog to print instead, without changing any setting, the document prints in color. How can I get back the color option so I can print from Chrome without the extra steps? According to Chrome help docs, the option should be there...

Comment: Bump. Anybody? ...

Comment: I try to save my web page as PDF and the font colors in the output PDF are only black/white. Strange problem.